# Creating browser - Error message when saving `URL` as String in list?

Tags: java, browser, runtime-error

I'm creating a simple web `browser` with 4 `JButtons`, a `JTextfield` and a `JEditorPane`. I want to save down every `URL` that I've visited in an `ArrayList` called `list`. One of my 4 `JButtons` is called `History`, if the user presses this button I want `list` to be printed.

Everytime the user writes something in `JTextfield` in the web browser, writes down a `URL` and presses enter, this method is called upon:

```
private void loadURL(String URL) {
    try {
        display.setPage(URL);
        addressBar.setText(URL);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Fel URL!");
    }
    //list.add(URL);
}
```

Notice that I've commented out `//list.add(URL);`. If I remove `//` from this line, my code gives an error message everytime, it says:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException`

I don't get what the problem is, I'm just trying to save down every `URL` I have visited, I don't see why this single line should give me an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you must initiate your list. Like:

```
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you forgot it you will get a NPE when trying to access your list's methods.

Check your code and see if you're doing it.

Comment: Hi, I'm doing this in the beginning: `private ArrayList<String> list;`

Comment: Then do this: private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Otherwise you're just creating a reference of type ArrayList that points to nothing, thus your null pointer exception.

Comment: check this out: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `list` object is not initialized and its null.

Create `list` object like this,

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```